# Slim php. Trigger bootstrap modal on specifik route

Tags: javascript, php, slim-3

Im setting up this site using the slim 3 framework for routing. When a certain url is requested i want a modal to popup, but not the whole app to re render its current view.

For example, when this below is done i instead want to init the modal.

Route:

```
$app->get('', function() {
    return new SettingsController('settings/index.twig');
});
```

Comment: BS modal is Front-End while PHP is Back-End. PHP can't trigger js. Put your modal in same page, on link click show modal `$('#my-modal').modal('show')`

Comment: I certanly knoww that. But the thing is that i still want to keep the modal in a route so you can reach it without click. The view itself also need a controller.

Comment: So open modal on window load

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: `<script>$(function () {$('#my-modal').modal()})();</script>`

Comment: yes, but how do i bind that modal to only opens on the specific route?